# Which Merge do I need?

Tags: r, merge

I am finding merge a difficult concept (*inner, outer, right, left*...) so forgive the simplistic question.
I want to merge each column that is generated to the column that came before.

```
labelA <- array(letters[1:10], dim=c(10,1))

## Function: test_values ##
test_func = function(df, nameA, nameB) {
test_values <- array(data=1, dim=c(10,1))
for (i in 1:10){
   test_values[i] <- paste(nameA, nameB, i, sep="_")
   }
merge (x=df, y=test_values, sort=FALSE, all=TRUE) # ??
}

# Comparison #1
nameA <-"A"
nameB <-"B"
gran_total = test_func(labelA, nameA, nameB)

# Comparison #2
nameA <-"C"
nameB <-"D"
gran_total = test_func(gran_total, nameA, nameB)
```

But my output is a matrix of *30 rows by 1 column*.

BUT ***I want*** (cannot figure out how to return) a matrix of **10 rows and 3 columns**

```
V1 V2     V3  
a  A_B_1  C_D_1  
b  A_B_2  C_D_2  
c  A_B_3  C_D_3  
d  A_B_4  C_D_4  
e  A_B_5  C_D_5
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably what you need is `cbind` or `data.frame` instead of `merge`.

Here is an example:

```
> labelA <- array(letters[1:3], dim=c(3,1))

> # simple way
> data.frame(labelA, paste("A", "B", 1:3, sep = "_"), paste("C", "D", 1:3, sep = "_"))
  labelA paste..A....B...1.3..sep...._.. paste..C....D...1.3..sep...._..
1      a                           A_B_1                           C_D_1
2      b                           A_B_2                           C_D_2
3      c                           A_B_3                           C_D_3

> # generalize as a function
> f <- function(df, nA, nB) paste(nA, nB, 1:nrow(df), sep = "_")
> data.frame(labelA, f(labelA, "A", "B"), f(labelA, "C", "D"))
  labelA f.labelA...A....B.. f.labelA...C....D..
1      a               A_B_1               C_D_1
2      b               A_B_2               C_D_2
3      c               A_B_3               C_D_3

> # more generalize for flexible arguments
> f2 <- function(df, labels)
+   data.frame(df, do.call("cbind", llply(labels, 
+     function(x) do.call("paste", c(as.list(x), list(1:nrow(df)), sep = "_")))))

> f2(labelA, list(c("A", "B"), c("C", "D")))
  df    X1    X2
1  a A_B_1 C_D_1
2  b A_B_2 C_D_2
3  c A_B_3 C_D_3

> f2(labelA, list(c("A", "B"), c("C", "D"), c("E", "F", "G")))
  df    X1    X2      X3
1  a A_B_1 C_D_1 E_F_G_1
2  b A_B_2 C_D_2 E_F_G_2
3  c A_B_3 C_D_3 E_F_G_3
```

Comment: I found **data.frame** worked best.  I should have figured... I tried *cbind* but could not get it to work. Cheers, K